# Alternative to NSOrderedSet in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using Swift 1.2, which introduces, as one of its many new language features, `Set`.

But I have yet to find alternative to `NSOrderedSet`. `Set` works as unordered set only.

Am I missing something here or isn't there any native implementation of `NSOrderedSet` just yet in Swift?

Thank you!

Comment: That is right, there only Set implemented in Swift yet, nothing like unordered set, so right now, you should implement your own, or use NSOrderedSet.

Comment: @DánielNagy Right. Thanks that's all I needed! Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it in case someone wonders too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is right, there only `Set` implemented in Swift yet, nothing like unordered set, so right now, you should implement your own, or use `NSOrderedSet`.